# Duplicate image show in recycle view in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In recycle view the image shown duplicate sometimes. what is the reason to show the duplicate image.Not the all time sometime its occure

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvSubject.setText(chatSessions.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvMessage.setText(chatSessions.get(position).getLastUnreadMsg());
        holder.tvTime.setText(chatSessions.get(position).getTime());

        final String pictureLink = ServerRequestHandler.getPictureLink(chatSessions.get(position).getCsToken());

        Log.d("ChatListAdapter", position + ", pictureLink= " + pictureLink);
        Log.d("ChatListAdapter", chatSessions.get(position).getName() + ", Time= " + chatSessions.get(position).getTime());

        holder.profileLoadingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.profilePicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.profilePicture.setImageDrawable(null);

        if (TaskUtils.isNotEmpty(pictureLink)) {

            imageLoader.displayImage((MainPageActivity) context, pictureLink, holder.profilePicture, holder.profileLoadingView);
        } else {
//            imageLoader.displayImage(null, holder.profilePicture, holder.profileLoadingView);

//            holder.profilePicture.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.photo));


            holder.profilePicture.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
```

I have added the screenn shot 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12ixq.png)

Comment: post your screenshot here

Comment: pictureLink is linking to a different image?

Comment: Its because of imageloader library, it caches images for fast loading

Comment: @ArunShankar how to solve the problem . have any idea?

Comment: @Christopher yes picture link is different

Answer (score 1):

The adapter have callback `onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder)` you can use it to stop loading the image, and/or clear the cache of the already loader image. You have to check how does your image loading library works, and how to do it

Comment: I dont have idea about how to clear the cache . can you give the example code

Comment: No, as i dont know what `imageLoader` is. Also cache might not be the culprit- you have to cancel the loadin of the image in this callback

Comment: its create another problem ...any other solution ?